# Comparing javascript dates are not working correctly

Tags: javascript, date

I'm following Daniel's answer here : [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

But it's not working as is should. This is my code:

`selectedDateEnd` is a date selected from jQuery UI Datepicker
`controller` is the a date from a list (last date added (in the future))
`12096e5` is a magic number which is 14 days in milliseconds.

A user can only create a new item that is 14 days older than the last item created.

```
    if(+selectedDateEnd >= (+controller + 12096e5)){
        cl('selectedDateEnd >= controller');
        cl(selectedDateEnd + ' >= ' + controller);
    } else {
        cl('selectedDateEnd < controller');
        cl(selectedDateEnd + ' < ' + controller);
    }
```

And the output is this:

```
selectedDateEnd < controller
Thu Feb 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 < Thu Feb 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

According to the logic, it should output:

```
    Thu Feb 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 >= Thu Feb 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

What have I done wrong here? See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueoxv9w7/

Comment: try using getTime() on the date objects

Comment: where are your dates coming from? why are you adding `12096e5` to controller?

Comment: in your post, it seem that both dates are the same, and the first statement is adding 14 days to the second date, so it's the expected behavior

Comment: @Hacketo—the use of unary '+' has the same effect as *getTime*, it returns the internal time value.

Comment: The opposite of `+selectedDateEnd >= (+controller + 12096e5)` is **not** `selectedDateEnd < controller`.

Comment: Really? Why the minus? It's an honest question.

Comment: Not my downvote but it's not really a technical question, just a "brain fart" so to speak.

Comment: It may be, but I'm still not able to getting working. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueoxv9w7/

Comment: `setTime()`, not `getTime()`. http://jsfiddle.net/ueoxv9w7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only adding the magic number in the `if` condition, and not when you print out the dates.

Do this:

```
//12096e5 is a magic number which is 14 days in milliseconds.
controller.setTime(+controller + 12096e5);
if(+selectedDateEnd >= +controller){
    cl('selectedDateEnd >= controller');
    cl(selectedDateEnd + ' >= ' + controller);
} else {
    cl('selectedDateEnd < controller');
    cl(selectedDateEnd + ' < ' + controller);
}
```

Comment: @Steven You're using `getTime` where it should be `setTime`.